# WPF: How to find ColumnHeader to my Column?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, gridviewcolumn

I'd like the users of my program to be able to decide for themselves, which columns they'd like to see in my ListView/GridView.

For that I created two attached properties for `GridViewColumn`, one is called `IsColumnVisible` of type `Boolean` (toggling visibility of the column on and off) and the other one is called `LastWidth` of type `Double` (holding the width of this column when it was last visible).

The property `IsColumnVisible` does have an `OnChangedCallback`.
When the property is set to `False`, I save the current width of the column in my property `LastWidth` and set the current width to 0.
When the property is set to `True`, I get the last width of the column from my property `LastWidth` and set the current width to that value.

This works so far, but with the flaw, that one can resize the hidden columns with the mouse to be visible again. So, if you have three columns and you hide the middle one, resizing the first one with the mouse ends up in making the second column visible again.

To get rid of that I wanted to set the `IsEnabled` state of the headers of the hidden columns to `False` and that's where the problem begins.

Let's say my columns are defined in XAML like this (columns 1 and 4 visible, columns 2 and 3 hidden):

```
<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
    <GridViewColumn Header="Column 1" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1}" local:GridViewColumnConfig.IsColumnVisible="True" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Column 2" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}" local:GridViewColumnConfig.IsColumnVisible="False" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Column 3" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column3}" local:GridViewColumnConfig.IsColumnVisible="False">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Column 4" />
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Column 4" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column4}" local:GridViewColumnConfig.IsColumnVisible="True" />
</GridView>
```

Since the default value of my property `IsColumnVisible` is `True`, my `OnChangedCallback` of this property only runs for columns 2 and 3.

I have an object of type `GridViewColumn` in the `OnChangedCallback` and to be able to set the `IsEnabled` state of the column header I need to determine the `GridViewColumnHeader` of my `GridViewColumn`.
A `GridViewColumn` has a property `Header` of type `Object`. In case of column 2 this property contains the `String` "Column 2", in case of column 3 this property is `Nothing`.

Is there any way to get the header of my `GridViewColumn` as a `GridViewColumnHeader` object?

In case of column 2 I could create a `GridViewColumnHeader` object myself, set it's `Content` to the value of the `Header` property and then set the `Header` property to this object.
But I'd rather not do those changes if I don't have to.

In case of column 3 there already should be a `GridViewColumnHeader` object somewhere (since I defined it in XAML), but I can't find it.
I already tried to walk the Visual Tree, but since `GridViewColumn` is not a `Visual` or a `Visual3D`, that's not possible.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the header of my `GridViewColumn` as a `GridViewColumnHeader` object?

The easiest way to do this would be to set the value of your custom attached property *after* you have set the value of the `Header` property.

You could do this if you switch to using element syntax:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column3}" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Column 4" />
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
    <local:GridViewColumnConfig.IsColumnVisible>
        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
    </local:GridViewColumnConfig.IsColumnVisible>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Then you will be able to simply cast the `Header` property to a `GridViewColumnHeader` in your `PropertyChangedCallback`:

```
Private Shared Sub OnPropertyChanged(d As GridViewColumn, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim header = TryCast(d.Header, GridViewColumnHeader)
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: So, there's actually no implicit GridViewColumnHeader when I use the attribute syntax for the header (like in column 2)?

Comment: The problem is that the Header property is set *before* your IsColumnVisible property when you use attribute syntax and that's why the Header property returns Nothing in your callback.

Comment: Since I'd have to remember to use the element syntax everytime I want to use this attached behavior, and since I'd more like to be remembered than to remember myself... do you have any suggestions on how or where to raise an exception if my property is set before the header?

Comment: The best you could do is to throw an exception if the Header propery returns Nothing in your PropertyChangedCallback.

Comment: And back to my first comment, there is no implicit creation of a GridViewColumnHeader, when I use the <GridViewColumn Header="..." /> syntax?